# select unique combinations of 5 columns of a table with 8 columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a master table
 containing 8 columns and I want to select unique
 combinations of 5 columns.how can i do that in `sqlserver`?

```
EDIT:i need to retrieve all 8 columns that have 5 unique columns.
```

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Do you mean that you want rows where 5 out of the 8 columns have different values? Example data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select distinct col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
from YourTable
```

This can also be achieved by doing:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
from YourTable
group by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
```

**EDIT**: To retrieve all 8 columns with 5 unique, you need to decide how to aggregate those 3 columns.  In other words, something like this:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, max(col6), min(col7), sum(col8)
from YourTable
group by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
```

In other words, if you aren't grouping by a particular column you logically need to decide how you want to retrieve the other columns.  See [this MSDN reference on Aggregate Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) to find all of the possible functions that you can use for aggregation.